# AWS signature generation

Tags: amazon-web-services

How can I generate AWS signature for getting data from the AWS url?

I have the following credentials.

```
$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX';
$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
```

And the following url

```
url="https://ow9hw5rtpk.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev/getOrderStatus?order_id=XXXXX&zip=XXXX";
```

I have to take data from the above url. I tried some code in php with cUrl from several post, but did not get the expected json formatted output.

I get the output when I run the following code that I got from postman test interface, but the signature is a static one. Please add or edit the below code for generating dynamic aws signature.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
$datestamp = time();
$date = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s e',$datestamp);
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://ow9hw5rtpk.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com  /dev/getOrderStatus?email=XXX@XXXX.NET&zip=XXXX",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>0,
  CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>0,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAIV4KH3BTCPT3E6FA/20180112/us-west-2/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date, Signature=cf871e46b14f48ef7e08e003250f6fcf7d0a90c5ca29b51ff9f6eae0eb104cdb",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Postman-Token: 3bea6936-0a81-e723-ee36-9e08a219a975",
    "X-Amz-Date: 20180112T110821Z"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `x-amz-content-sha256` is missing in `Authorization`,  so after adding that below stuff will also change (value of sha256 will be generated through functions-SDK)
from

```
SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-date
```

To

```
SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
```

In general, I would encourage to prepare Auth header with [SDKs provided by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Common.Signature.SignatureV4.html)